# Warnings when creating traineddata file from png/box : Parameters not found -> tessedit_single_match and il1_adaption_test

Tags: parameters, warnings, tesseract

I am trying to create a new training file with a specific test_font.traineddata file from a png/box set created with jTessBoxEditor.

When executing the line:

```
tesseract %PATH%/test_font.test_font.exp0.png %PATH%/test_font.test_font.exp0 nobatch box.train
```

I get the warning messages:

```
Warning: Parameter not found: tessedit_single_match
Warning: Parameter not found: il1_adaption_test
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v5.0.0-alpha.20191030 with Leptonica
APPLY_BOXES:
   Boxes read from boxfile: 192
   Found 192 good blobs.
   Leaving 6 unlabelled blobs in 0 words.
Generated training data for 46 words
```

This seems not catastrophic because I'm still able to generate the unicharset file afterwards.
But I would like to know where these warnings come from, if I can correct them and what their impact is.

After that, during the execution of the command:

```
mftraining -F font_properties -U unicharset -O %PATH%/test_font.unicharset %PATH%/test_font.test_font.exp0.tr
```

I get the messages:

```
Warning: No shape table file present: shapetable
Reading %PATH%/test_font.test_font.exp0.tr ...
Flat shape table summary: Number of shapes = 60 max unichars = 1 number with multiple unichars = 0
Warning: no protos / configs for Joined in CreateIntTemplates ()
Warning: no protos / configs for | Broken | 0 | 1 in CreateIntTemplates ()
Done!
```

Do you know what the impact of these new warnings is and how to fix them?

Thank you very much in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that theses parameters *tessedit_single_match* and *il1_adaption_test* had been added inadvertently by a wrong command line in the Tesseract-OCR\tessdata\configs\box.train and Tesseract-OCR\tessdata\configs\lstm.train files.

The correct structure for these files seems to be respectively:

```
disable_character_fragments T
file_type                   .bl
textord_fast_pitch_test T
tessedit_zero_rejection T
tessedit_minimal_rejection F
tessedit_write_rep_codes F
edges_children_fix F 
edges_childarea 0.65
edges_boxarea 0.9
tessedit_resegment_from_boxes T
tessedit_train_from_boxes T
textord_no_rejects T
```

And

```
file_type                   .bl
textord_fast_pitch_test T
tessedit_zero_rejection T
tessedit_minimal_rejection F
tessedit_write_rep_codes F
edges_children_fix F
edges_childarea 0.65
edges_boxarea 0.9
tessedit_train_line_recognizer T
textord_no_rejects T
tessedit_init_config_only T
```

This seems to solve the first warning problems but not the no protos/configs.